# How to make integer round off to hundredths place

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In actionscript 3, I have a user enter a number into a field and this field is supposed to be for a cash value. How do I make it so that if for some reason they put say 20.956, it would round up to 20.96?

Comment: soooo simple Math.round(NumberToRound*100)/100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`toFixed()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed%28%29). Something like:

```
var cash:String = (Number("1.2365")).toFixed(2)
```

It's not mentioned in the documetnation, but i'm fairly sure it rounds rather than floors.

Notice that `.toFixed()` returns a string, if you want a more comprehensive helper then you could use something like the following.

```
    public function rounder(num:Number, decimalPlaces:int, method:Function = null):Number {
        if(method == null) method = Math.round;
        var mul:Number = Math.pow(10,decimalPlaces);
        return method(num * mul)/mul;
    }
```

and invoke it using:

```
rounder(1.245, 2); // returns 1.25  (it uses round by default)
rounder(1.245, 2, Math.floor); // returns 1.24
rounder(1.241, 2, Math.ceil); // returns 1.25
```

And actually you can use negative numbers for the decimalPlaces as well

```
rounder(2123, -1, Math.ceil); // returns 2130
```